# How reliable is using the constructors name as type?

Tags: javascript, types, constructor, typeof

I've seen this about a lot recently, even in new programming languages that compile to javascript, where they have replaced `typeof` with `item.constructor.name`

How reliable is this and is there any pros <sup>*(except the Array type)*</sup> and cons?

here is an example

```
var tmp = [];

typeof tmp // object

tmp.constructor.name // Array
```

Answer (score 2):

`name` as property of a function is part of the upcoming ES6 standard and currently [supported by all browsers expect IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Browser_compatibility). Aside that, it should be fine to use for built-in objects.

Objects created by user defined constructor functions OTOH might not have the correct `constructor` property set, e.g. in cases where inheritance was used but the value of `constructor` wasn't set back to the constructor function:

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
// Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

---

tl;dr:

Built-in objects and non-IE browsers: reliable
Third party user defined constructor functions or IE: not reliable

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of cons off the top of my head:

**1) Browser support.**

It was covered by Felix Kling's answer, non-IE works well. IE - not so much, though i suppose workarounds are possible.

**2) Custom constructors**

```
var Foo = function(){};
var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.constructor.name); // empty string
```

Of course, this can be mitigated by enforcing a style where constructors are not allowed to be anonymous functions, or invent a crazy workaround.

```
var Foo = function Foo(){};

function Bar(){};

var Baz = function (){};
Baz.name = 'Baz';
```

**3) Exceptions**

typeof doesn't throw exceptions. Because of this it is used to check if a variable hasn't been defined:

```
if (typeof baz === 'undefined') console.log('baz not defined');
if (baz === undefined) console.log('Reference error instead!');
```

Even worse, checking constructor.name throws a TypeError for null and undefined values. This can probably be mitigated by using:

```
foo != null && foo.constructor.name
```

**4) Wrapper objects.**

There are some edge cases where typeof and item.constructor.name return conflicting results:

```
var foo = false;
var bar = new Boolean(false);

console.log(typeof foo);  // boolean
console.log(typeof bar);  // object
console.log(foo.constructor.name);  // Boolean
console.log(bar.constructor.name);  // Boolean

if (foo) console.log('No');
if (bar) console.log('Yes');
```

There are few scenarios where these actually matter, the above is pretty much the worst case.

**5) Speed**

I would expect a native operator to be much faster than 2 property checks, though if this idea gets traction it will probably be better optimized as well. Either way, i can't imagine this ever being the bottleneck of your application.

---

All in all, there are quite a few disadvantages and i can't think of a strong reason to use it.